# Regex to Extract particular string

Tags: java

I have following strings from this i have to extract only
following `LSA,List, BROWSER2, Marmiton, BROWSER`. That means the string after the extension of .log.
How I can do it?

```
 /opt/Seloger/.RFC_LSA.log
 /opt/Seloger/.RFC_List.log
 /opt/Seloger/.RFC_RDK_BROWSER2.log 
  /opt/Seloger/.RFC_List_src_Marmiton.log
 /opt/Seloger/.RFC_RDK_BROWSER.log
```

Comment: what have you tried, even indexOf and substring could do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of regex but this method will also work

1) get the last index of underscore:-

```
int last=str.lastIndexOf('_');
```

2) get the last index of '.'

```
int lastD=str.lastIndexOf('.');
```

3) use the substring function to get the desired string.

```
String result=str.substring(last+1,lastD);
```

You can also short the code by writing

```
String result=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('_')+1,str.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex which uses positive look ahead:

```
[^_/]+(?=\.)
```

Here is the demo: https://regex101.com/r/1fP5Hy/1